# Remember my username checkbox on ForgeRock Login when Authentication happens on Trees

Tags: openam, forgerock

I have one use case where I want to implement Authentication Login page and want have checkbox Remember my username. How to do that on Trees ?

Any link to that would be helpful.

Do I need to modify XUI ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know openam store "remember my username" in a plaintext cookie, most modern browsers implement a better alternative, but if you still want to the use native function, you should change the html (of the tree) file and append :

```
  {{#if isSubmit}}
                {{#if ../../showRememberLogin}}
                    {{> login/_RememberLogin }}
                {{/if}}
            {{/if}}
```

Src:  https://github.com/OpenRock/OpenAM/blob/master/openam-ui/openam-ui-ria/src/main/resources/templates/openam/authn/DataStore1.html

https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-11800